# Function for calculating the inverse of the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind in Legendre normal form.

Tags: matlab, mathematica, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

The matlab function ellipj(U,M) calculate the inverse of the trigonometric form. Is there a matlab function for calculating the inverse of the legender normal form of the incomplete elliptic integral?

[image: form of the function]

Comment: $sn$ is defined by its series of poles of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_functions#Weierstrass_zeta_function) form

Comment: Is there a matlab function for this?

Comment: `L = ([-N:N]*tau).'* [-N:N];  sum( 1./(z + [-N:N]').^2); ...`

Comment: If: k^2=0.455;  and tau=3.795; What is N,z,tau and what should I type in matlab?

Comment: I need the inverse function of the integral in the picture. Do you know if there is a table of value for this?